# Wordpress: How can I make the responsive header bigger in height?

Tags: php, css, wordpress

[image]

I need the make the height larger to allow the logo to be more visible. Is this a CSS issue? If so, where can I find it in Wordpress?

Answer (score 0):

I see that there is an inline style on your logo with *max-width:161px;*
You can raise that up to 260px and the look will still look fine.. 
Changing the height of the navbar will not change the looks of the logo itself.

so either you do it inline again and change accordingly:

```
<img alt="Resuscitation Academy" src="...ra_logo_large2.png" style="max-width: 260px;">
```

or you update your styles.css to reflect this

```
.logo .img{
    max-width:260px;
}
```

Maybe you could also rearrange the logo to fit better into the space available. (lots of text in that logo)

Comment: I am using the Wiz Corporate theme. 

URL: http://laerdalevents.com/resuscitation_academy/